# Time derivative does not satisfy the differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the time-varying matrix $A(t) = [1 ,1; 0, t ]$ calculate the exponential of $\int_0 ^t A(s) ds$, and
verify that its time derivative does not satisfy the differential equations $\phi^{'}(t) = A(t)\phi(t).$
How we show that time derivative does not satisfy the differential equations $\phi^{'}(t) = A(t)\phi(t)$ by using the limit?

Answer (score 0):

$$\phi ^{'} (t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}[\phi (t+h)- \phi (t)]$$
$$\phi^{'}(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}[e^{\int_0 ^{t+h}A(s)ds}-e^{\int_0 ^t A(s)ds}].$$
If, we have commute, then we can separate,
$$\phi ^{'} (t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}[e^{\int_0 ^{t} A(s)ds+\int_t ^{t+h} A(s)ds }-e^{\int_0 ^t A(s)ds}]$$
$$=e^{\int _0 ^t A(s)ds}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}e^{\int_0 ^{t+h} A(s)ds}$$
that my think.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: calculate the integral explicitly, and exponentiate that matrix.

Comment: I got that $\phi ^{'}(t)=0\neq A(t) \phi (t).$

Comment: No, it's obviously not $0$.

Comment: yes, I find that e^{K+L}\neq e^K * e^L since KL\neq LK

Answer (score 0):

The integral of $A=[t,t; 0, t^2/2]$

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answer..